# does the gremlin-java API use the OrientDB fields for 1:1 or 1:many relationships?

Tags: java, orientdb, gremlin

In the [Schema documentation](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Schema.html#1-1-and-n-1-reference-relationships), it appears to be possible to define edges as field names. If I add something here, e.g. a 1:1 `OType.LINK`, will the [Graph API](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Graph-Database-Tinkerpop.html) make use of this information when I use `addEdge(...)` and a query with `getEdges(...)`, or must I use some vendor-specific methods to get at this feature?

There is a configuration option `useVertexFieldsForEdgeLabels`, which appears relevant, but it's not clear how everything all links together (sorry, couldn't resist that one). e.g. why are field name and edge type separate parameters; it sounds like they should always be the same.